# Gray UserControl out if enabled = false during design time

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my first question and I have a UserControl which contains other controls like label and picturebox. If I disable the UserControl, the other controls should be disabled during designtime too. That means: if I disable the UserControl, the picturebox should be grayed out instantly.

Every time when the "EnabledChanged"-Event triggers, the picturebox will enabled or disabled, but didn't grayed out during designtime. If I run the code, the picturebox is gray.

```
private void ProgressButtonImageText_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   if (Enabled == false)    
       pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
   else
       pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
}
```

I want that the pictureBox is grayed out when I change the property on designer. Not if I run the code, only before! I noticed that the "EnabledChanged"-Event doesn't triggers on design time, only runtime. Other events like "Click" triggers on designtime too!
How can I reach the expected result?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why you want this at designtime ? If your control would be really disabled at designtime you would not be able to manipulate it anymore also, have you considered that ?

Comment: @GuidoG I only want the effect like a textBox. If I set the textBox to ReadOnly it's grayed out. I want the same effect because it's "easier to understand" for the developer, that the control isn't available during runtime for the user.

Comment: Its not because the control looks disabled at designtime it will also be disabled at runtime. That can change in code. So if the control is enabled at runtime after all, this will create the same confusion again, wont it ?

Comment: Anyway, you cant have the disabled look without actually disabling, and the designer probably wont change the control to disabled at designtime. In other words, I dont think this is possible

Comment: Side note : your method can be simplified to `pictureBox1.Enabled = Enabled`

Comment: What is a grayed-out PictureBox? The Image it contains should turn grayscale? It's BackColor should be set to Color.Gray? What is the grayed aspect of it? Can you give an example of it disabled the way you mean it?

Comment: @Jimi The color of the picture turns gray, if the picture contains blue, the blue change to gray. [Example](https://ibb.co/vBSPZ9y) This should happen if I disable my UserControl.

Comment: That's not `Color.Blue` becoming `Color.Gray`. That's a gray-scaled Bitmap. You need to apply a [ColorMatrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix) to the Image. Or have two different versions of the same Image in two different color ranges. I suggest the former.

Comment: @Jimi Ah okay, and which Matrix I need to change? For example: if I want to make some picture opacity, then I use the ColorMatrix.33.

Comment: [How to: Use a Color Matrix to Set Alpha Values in Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-a-color-matrix-to-set-alpha-values-) -- [How to: Draw with Opaque and Semitransparent Brushes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-draw-with-opaque-and-semitransparent-brushes). If you want to apply a ColorMatrix, the GrayScale ColorMatrix is a pre-defined. combination of float values. You just apply the combination you think is appropriate, in relation to the *look* you want to achieve.

Comment: A ColorMatrix renders very fast, but you must be careful to dispose of any object you use in this situation, otherwise you'll leak Graphics resources at a equally fast pace.

Comment: @Jimi So far so good, now I have a problem. If I override my "Enabled"-property, the changes on the picture works only during runtime. If I create my own property (for e.g. "Enabled2") then it works and the picture is updating during designtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to show you my result (if you had the same question). I'm not completely happy, because I can't override the "Enabled"-property. (In the comments under my question I wrote my "new problem")

Whatever..

First of all I created a new property

```
private bool enabled = true;
public new bool Enabled2 {
    get {...}
    set {...}
}
```

Then I modified the "setter" from the property with my new function:

```
public new bool Enabled2 {
            get { return enabled; }
            set {
                this.Enabled = enabled = pictureEdit1.Enabled = labelControl1.Enabled = value;
                if (pictureEdit1.Image != null && !enabled)
                    pictureEdit1.Image = setImageDisabled(pictureEdit1.Image);
                else
                    //buttonImage is a property which saves the "normal" image
                    pictureEdit1.Image = buttonImage;

                //without this, the Image doesn't update
                if (DesignMode)
                    Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

And last but not least, my function "setImageDisabled":

```
    private Image setImageDisabled(Image image) {
            try {
                Image grayedImage = ToolStripRenderer.CreateDisabledImage(image);
                return grayedImage;
            } catch { return null; }
        }
```

The only reason why I want to override the "Enabled"-property is, that if a other developer use this UserControl, the picture should be grayed out if he disable the whole control.

Comment: Good start. Do you want to test it with a ColorMatrix instead? This way, you could personalize the color aspect the way you want. Setting it to, say, sepia or black&white or whatever else.

Comment: @Jimi If I have time, yes, but not now ;D this was the (for me) fastest way, with not much code.

Comment: I meant, if you want I can post a sample of a UserControl that implements that behaviour using a ColorMatrix.

Comment: @Jimi if you think this is faster, then go for it.